# Clicks not working as taps in Xcode preview?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode-previews

I followed [a cool YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzQDKYIKEb8) to make a random TabBar and initially it was all working just fine and then something happened and the taps now are just inert. Nothing happens!

I tried changing the target architecture in build settings but nothing helped. Is the code somehow bad (it looks materially identical to the video's) or is Xcode just...?

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum ActionIcon: String, CaseIterable {
  case Home = "house"
  case Library = "books.vertical"
  case Performer = "dot.radiowaves.left.and.right"
  case Editor = "dial.medium"
  case Comms = "bolt.horizontal.circle"
  //case Prefs = "gearshape"
}

struct NavBar: View {
  @Binding var selectedTab: ActionIcon
  
  private var selectedIcon: String {
    if selectedTab != .Performer {
      return selectedTab.rawValue+".fill"
    } else {
      return selectedTab.rawValue
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
        ForEach(ActionIcon.allCases, id:\.rawValue) { tab in
          Spacer()
          Image(systemName: selectedTab == tab ? selectedIcon : tab.rawValue )
            .scaleEffect(tab == selectedTab ? 1.28  : 1.0)
            .foregroundColor(tab == selectedTab ? Color("GROrange"): Color.primary)
            .font(.system(size:18))
            .onTapGesture {
              withAnimation(.easeIn(duration:0.1)) {
                selectedTab = tab
              }
            }
          Spacer()
        }
      }
      .frame(height: 60)
      .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
      .cornerRadius(50)
      .padding()
    }
  }
}

struct NavBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    @State var stab:ActionIcon = .Library
    return NavBar(selectedTab: $stab)
  }
}
```